# C++ Polymorphism / Class Dependency Error

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

I am using C++ to make a basic family with polymorphism. However, I get errors when I compile, and I am not sure how to correct them (I say `class dependency`, as Parent and Child both depend on each other before the other is created):

> error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Parent'
>
> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> error C2065: 'parent' : undeclared identifier
>
> error C2065: 'name' : undeclared identifier
>
> error C2614: 'Child' : illegal member initialization: 'par' is not a
>   base or member
>
> error C2065: 'par' : undeclared identifier
>
> error C2227: left of '->addChild' must point to
>   class/struct/union/generic type
>
> error C2065: 'par' : undeclared identifier
>
> error C2227: left of '->Name' must point to class/struct/union/generic
>   type
>
> error C2661: 'Child::Child' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
>
> error C2065: 'par' : undeclared identifier
>
> error C2227: left of '->Name' must point to class/struct/union/generic
>   type

```
/* Polymorphism Family */
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Child{
public:
    Child(Parent* parent, char* name) : par(parent), Name(name){ par->addChild(this); };
    Parent* par;
    char* Name;
    virtual void Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a child, my name is " << Name << " and my parent's name is " << par->Name << std::endl;
    }
};
class Parent{
public:
    Parent(char* name) : Name(name){};
    char* Name;
    std::vector<Child*> Children;
    virtual void Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a parent called " << Name << std::endl;
        if(Children.size() == 0){
            std::cout << "I have no children" << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "I have " << Children.size() << " children:" << std::endl;
            for(auto c : Children){
                std::cout << c->Name;
            }
        }
    }
    void addChild(Child* child){
        Children.push_back(child);
    }
};
class Father : public Parent{
public:
    Father(char* name) : Parent(name){}
    void Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a father called " << Name << std::endl;
        if(Children.size() == 0){
            std::cout << "I have no children" << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "I have " << Children.size() << " children:" << std::endl;
            for(Child* c : Children){
                std::cout << c->Name;
            }
        }
    }
};
class Son : public Child{
public:
    Son(Parent* parent, char* name) : Child(parent, name){}
    void Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a son, my name is " << Name << " and my parent's name is " << par->Name << std::endl;
    }
};
int main(void){
    Father* Dad = new Father("James");
    Dad->Speak();
    Son* John = new Son(Dad, "John");
    John->Speak();
    Dad->Speak();
    delete[] Dad, John;
    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

**Edit: I have 2 errors now:**

```
/* Polymorphism Family */
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Parent;

class Child{
public:
    Child(Parent* parent, char* name);
    Parent* par;
    char* Name;
    virtual void Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a child, my name is " << Name << " and my parent's name is " << par->Name << std::endl;
    }
};

class Parent{
public:
    Parent(char* name) : Name(name){};
    char* Name;
    std::vector<Child*> Children;
    virtual void Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a parent called " << Name << std::endl;
        if(Children.size() == 0){
            std::cout << "I have no children" << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "I have " << Children.size() << " child(ren):" << std::endl;
            for(auto c : Children){
                std::cout << c->Name << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    void addChild(Child* child){
        Children.push_back(child);
    }
};

Child::Child(Parent* parent, char* name){
    Child::par = parent;
    Child::Name = name;
    par->addChild(this); 
};

class Father : public Parent{
public:
    Father(char* name) : Parent(name){}
    void Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a father called " << Name << std::endl;
        if(Children.size() == 0){
            std::cout << "I have no children" << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "I have " << Children.size() << "child(ren):" << std::endl;
            for(auto c : Children){
                std::cout << c->Name << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};
class Son : public Child{
public:
    Son(Parent* parent, char* name) : Child(parent, name){}
    void Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a son, my name is " << Name << " and my parent's name is " << par->Name << std::endl;
    }
};
int main(void){
    Father* Dad = new Father("James");
    Dad->Speak();
    Son* John = new Son(Dad, "John");
    John->Speak();
    Dad->Speak();
    delete[] Dad, John;
    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Use forward declarations to break cyclic dependencies. Also, `delete[] Dad, John` does not do what you think

Comment: Your code is very bad. See [_Modern C++_](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1) and [_The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Your compiler should output line numbers on it's error messages. There's a good reason for that!

Comment: Hi. @user2976089
have you checked this code by online compiler with options i'd provided in additional part of my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Child` class uses `Parent` class that hasn't been defined yet (not above on code, prior to `Child` or in some of included files). To fix this issue just declare `Parent` class  before (or "above") `Child`. For example:

```
class Parent;

//child class declaration as posted in your code and other classes include Parent.
class Child{
public:
    Child(Parent* parent, char* name) : par(parent), Name(name){ par->addChild(this); };
    Parent* par;
...
```

Hope this helps.

[Added]
Here is working example of code asked by author:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Child;

class Parent {

public:
    Parent(const char* name) : Name(name){};
    const char* Name;
    std::vector<Child*> Children;

    void Speak(void);
    void addChild(Child* child);
};

class Child{
public:
    Child(Parent* parent, const char* name) {
        Child::par = parent;
        Child::Name = name;
        par->addChild(this); 
    }

    Parent* par;
    const char* Name;
    virtual void Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a child, my name is " << Name << " and my parent's name is " << par->Name << std::endl;
    }
};

void Parent::Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a parent called " << Name << std::endl;
        if(Children.size() == 0){
            std::cout << "I have no children" << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "I have " << Children.size() << " child(ren):" << std::endl;
            for(auto c : Children){
                std::cout << c->Name << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }


void Parent::addChild(Child* child) {
        Children.push_back(child);
    }

class Father : public Parent{
public:
    Father(const char* name) : Parent(name){}
    void Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a father called " << Name << std::endl;
        if(Children.size() == 0){
            std::cout << "I have no children" << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "I have " << Children.size() << "child(ren):" << std::endl;
            for(auto c : Children){
                std::cout << c->Name << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

class Son : public Child{
public:
    Son(Parent* parent, const char* name) : Child(parent, name){}
    void Speak(void){
        std::cout << "I am a son, my name is " << Name << " and my parent's name is " << par->Name << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    //i suggest you to use stack-located variables against heap-located
    Father Dad("James");
    Dad.Speak();

    Son John(&Dad, "John");
    John.Speak();
    Dad.Speak();    

    // Father* Dad = new Father("James");
    // Dad->Speak();
    // Son* John = new Son(Dad, "John");
    // John->Speak();
    // Dad->Speak();
    // delete Dad; 
    // delete John;
    //getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

Output by [online cpp editor](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php)

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program....
$demo 
I am a father called James
I have no children
I am a son, my name is John and my parent's name is James
I am a father called James
I have 1child(ren):
John
```

Comment: I still get 4 errors though

Comment: Please, post that errors.

Comment: `Use of undefined parent` twice, `left of ->addChild must point to a class/struct/union/generic type`, `left of -> name must point to a...`

Comment: You should implement `Child` class constructor (where you invoke `Parent`) after you've implemented `Parent` class. E.g. `class Parent; class Child { Child(); ... } class Parent { ... } ... //"below" "Parent" class definition public Child::Child(Parent* parent, char* name) { /* invoke parent's method here */ }`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have edited it, but I still have two errors - `Use of undefined parent` and `left of -> name must point to a...`

Comment: Ok. You should add property `Name` with public access to `Parent` class declaration that located above `Child` class declaration. So `Child` class will know about `Parent`'s property `Name`.

Comment: How would I do that please - +1 and accepted answer if you can?